# What is a sequence of actions in a default MSI installation (not custom)?

Tags: windows-installer

An MSI installer calls a lot of pre-defined actions during install - FindRelatedProducts, CheckVersion, etc. Different actions are called during different install types and sequences: admin, unattended, user, execute, deffered... and custom actions are queued 'before' or 'after' these predefined MSI actions.

Is there a complete list available that shows the exact sequence in which MSI actions are called in different install modes and sequences? Ideally with short comments about what each action does and what is a good practice to insert custom actions into.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the MSDN documentation, specifically the documentation on [Using a Sequence Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372404(VS.85).aspx).

For offline reference, download the [Windows Installer 4.5 SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=6A35AC14-2626-4846-BB51-DDCE49D6FFB6&displaylang=en) and read **MSI.CHM** (it's much easier to navigate than the MSDN stuff anyway)

Comment: Look at the sequence table of the most simple installer you can imagine, that will show the default sequence for MSI files generated by that same tool under the same OS. It's not a simple set of defaults, it could vary based on inputs and API versions that were used in the build process. Without official publications, you need to work backwards unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer is very complex (after my experience with it I could say it is an euphemism for ridiculous mess) and I did not find any summary of required order of actions. However, the order for example in [Suggested InstallExecuteSequence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372038(v=vs.85).aspx) is suggested by MS, so it should work.