# Default Sequence number, what's determine it?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I am starting getting explored to the black magic of MSI. And one thing stuck on my currently is the seemly randomness of sequence number assigned in the sequence table, or the lack of document I can find. I encounter an issue with my MSI project as `AppSearch` been assigned a sequence number of 50, which is too low for my usage, and different from this [suggested install sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Msi/suggested-installuisequence), or [Sequence table example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Msi/sequence-table-detailed-example), which both seems reasonable. I just find out that I can easily change sequence number for all the standard actions myself, the issue itself is fixable for me.

But I am thinking that the sequence number been defined some where (either in MSI by Windows SDK? or wix) as default for a reason. The sequence of 50 for `AppSearch` is might for a good reason (or not so good ones and has been fixed already), or indeed somehow it is affected by a few different factors and is hard to track down and indeed appeared to be random as a result.

Currently my thinking is it is mostly likely been the default value determined by Wix, where is the document/or source code so I can find out then?

Ok, try to summarise my question better: **Can I have some control of what set of default sequence number, by using a particular version of Windows Install SDK, or Wix?**

Comment: Oh, it seems I can close MSI questions on my own now. Oh the humanity! Absolute power is very confusing for a hobbit. See you in the other "thread"! Ahoy!

Comment: Happy to close this question, as both have the same answer. But if I don't understand how a certain function library works, can I ask?

Comment: Just ask a new question at any time, but avoid duplicates please. Added some more links to my answer in your other question.

Comment: Thanks, guess I just need be more patient. Thought my other question may never attract much attention. But I got excellent answer, thanks for that.

Comment: That's good to hear. I will have a look at something else for you. Maybe you can write a JSON string to the registry and use that to serialize and de-serialize your persisted properties. But now we are doing what we are not supposed to, keeping a closed answer active. Will update other answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't see this question before I answered your other one. It is essentially the same question, so I might ask the guys to close this one as duplicate: **[AppSearch has sequence number 50 - right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52089710/appsearch-has-sequence-number-50-right/52106844#52106844)**

The specific answer to this flavour would be that you can try to change a WiX source file and compile WiX yourself - which is no small task I might add. Please see the above link for the actual file.